# How to correct this runtime error and why do i get it in Delphi?

Tags: api, delphi, request, runtime

I am trying to call a remote API function in Delphi:

```pascal
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  getBalance1 : getBalance;
  type1 : consenttype;
begin
  getBalance1.consent.type_ := type1;
  getBalance1.consent.target := Edit5.Text;
  getBalance1.consent.id := Edit6.Text;
    
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  valasz := (HTTPRio1 as AccountInfo_PT).getBalance(getBalance1);
end;
```

But at runtime, I get this error:

> Access violation at address 00791D72 in module generate_xml_exe. Write of address 0000000C.

What is this, and how can I correct it? I get this error when I click on the button at runtime.

`getBalance` is a class of `getBalance_Type`:

```pascal
  getBalance_Type = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fconsent: consent5;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property consent: consent5  Index (IS_UNQL) read Fconsent write Fconsent;
  end;
    
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : getBalance, global, <element>
  // Namespace : http://bbrt.hu/openApiServices/AccountInfo/1/
  // Info      : Wrapper
  // ************************************************************************ //
  getBalance = class(getBalance_Type)
  private
  published
  end;

  consent5 = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Ftype_: consentType;
    Ftarget: targetType;
    Fid: consentIdType;
  published
    property type_:  consentType    Index (IS_UNQL) read Ftype_ write Ftype_;
    property target: targetType     Index (IS_UNQL) read Ftarget write Ftarget;
    property id:     consentIdType  Index (IS_UNQL) read Fid write Fid;
  end;
```

These lines cause the runtime error:

```pascal
getBalance1.consent.type_ := type1;
getBalance1.consent.target := Edit5.Text;
getBalance1.consent.id := Edit6.Text;
```

But I don't know how to correct this.

Comment: At which line do you get the error? What type is _getBalance_?  What type is _HTTPRio1_ and _AccountInfo_PT_ ? Please show these in the code example, as without this information, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: getBalance_Type = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fconsent: consent5;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property consent: consent5  Index (IS_UNQL) read Fconsent write Fconsent;
  end;



    // XML       : getBalance, global, <element>
  // Namespace : http://bbrt.hu/openApiServices/AccountInfo/1/
  // Info      : Wrapper
  // ************************************************************************ //
  getBalance = class(getBalance_Type)
  private
  published
  end;    HTTPRIO1: THTTPRIO

Comment: I get the error when i click on the button in run time

Comment: These lines cause the runtime error : getBalance1.consent.type_ :=type1;
     getBalance1.consent.target :=Edit5.Text;
     getBalance1.consent.id :=Edit6.Text; but i don't know how to correct them ?

Comment: In the code you have posted getBalance1 is not created

Comment: Access Violations near address 0 usually mean a nil pointer is being accessed.

Comment: Thanks, i corrected it, now I am trying to make a call to an API from Delphi. It says that THTTPRrio.Create has not enough parameters. How can i call it the right way ? : HTTPRio1 :=THTTPRio.Create() ; valasz :=(HTTPRio1 as AccountInfo_PT).getBalance(getBalance1);

Comment: It feels to me like you are poking away blindly without knowing what you are dealing with (no offense intended). You need to understand the Delphi Class system and Object Inheritance in order to code the code you're trying to. Why do you do _(HTTPRio1 as AccountInfoPT)_ ? What are the type definitions of _HTTPRio_ and _AccountIntoPT_ ? Why do you cast _HTTPRio1_ to _AccountIfoPT_? Do you understand what this does?

Comment: I dont't know how to send the call to the API , i am just a beginner, i tried this way : valasz :=(HTTPRio1 as AccountInfo_PT).getBalance(getBalance1) because i saw this on some resource on the net in some pdf but i think it was an older version of Delphi. Now again i get that Acces Violation error in runtime, but getBalance1 is created, HTTPrio1 too, how should i call that function from the API ?

Comment: AccountInfo_PT = interface(IInvokable)

Comment: Not i get another Acces Violation from this line : valasz :=(HTTPRio1 as AccountInfo_PT).getBalance(getBalance1) , i should destroy all the objects that i created or what is the problem ? Acces violation at address : 00408708.  Read of address 0757C054. What should i do ?

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but you should start at a lower level. The code you are trying to do is not for beginners - you lack sufficient knowledge of Delphi Programming to do what you want to do. Don't try to build a car before you know how to weld... We can't see your entire project, and even if we could, you wouldn't understand the solution we presented you with. Start at ground level and work your way up to the penthouse - don't start building the penthouse before you have the ground floor finished...

Comment: Stop now what you are doing. To continuously add details, new errors etc. as comments to your question is wrong. It is not how SO works. You are welcome to ask **a well prepared question**, and at some point of time somebody might answer. You have got an answer to your original question about the AV. If the answer is correct, mark it as such (green tick mark beside the answer) and up vote. Post new questions for new issues.

Comment: Thank you for listening and acting accordingly. I also rolled back your last edit, in order for the answer and question to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of your Access Violation is that *getBalance1* of type *getBalance* is not created.

All CLASSes in Delphi need to be created, usually via a CONSTRUCTOR named Create. As you don't implicitly create the *getBalance1* variable, it contains a random value, and you cannot (safely) access its content.

So, before you start using the *getBalance1* variable, you need to create it, as in:

```
getBalance1 := getBalance.Create;
```

Comment: Also, dont forget to destroy the object when it’s no longer used using ‘getBalance1.Free;’